# How to place UI components uniformly using dip

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to make below UI for my android app.

**Specifications:**

1. UI contains total 4 sections (1-4).
2. Component 1,2 & 4 must be of same size.
3. Component 3 must be twice the size of component 1.

[image]

But how can I calculate the exact `dip` size so that all the component are uniformly sized on different sized screens?

If my approach is wrong then please advice.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If my approach is wrong then please advice.

Use a vertical `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight` on the children. If we pretend for a moment that the children are buttons, use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="1"/>

<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:text="2"/>

<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="3"/>

<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The result is:

[image: screenshot of layout]